# Character limit for ODE solver

Tags: r

I'm trying to solve some ODEs in R.

Currently I'm using the package deSolve, but am running into problems as there appears to be a character limit on the length of the equations, the error tells me there's an unexpected symbol.

Initially I solved this by storing half of the offending equation in another vector then combining... Ideally I would not like to do this for every equation.

Does anyone know a way around the character limit for this package, or of an ODE solver in R without a character limit?

As requested, here is an equation which causes the error unexpected symbol:

```
dyx31 <- -c_2*yx14*(-6*c_6^2*y_0 + 4*c_6^2 - 12*c_6*y_0^2 + 4*c_6*y_0 + 4*c_6*yx16 + c_6 - 6*y_0^3)/(c_6^3 + 3*c_6^2*y_0 + 3*c_6*y_0^2 + y_0^3) + c_2*yx29*(-4*c_6^3*y_0 + 6*c_6^3 - 12*c_6^2*y_0^2 + 12*c_6^2*y_0 + 4*c_6^2 - 12*c_6*y_0^3 + 6*c_6*y_0^2 + 4*c_6*y_0 + 4*c_6*yx16 + c_6 - 4*y_0^4)/(c_6^4 + 4*c_6^3*y_0 + 6*c_6^2*y_0^2 + 4*c_6*y_0^3 + y_0^4) - c_2*yx4*(4*c_6*y_0 - 4*c_6*yx16 - c_6 + 4*y_0^2)/(c_6^2 + 2*c_6*y_0 + y_0^2) + yx16*(4*c_0*c_6^4 + 16*c_0*c_6^3*y_0 + 24*c_0*c_6^2*y_0^2 + 16*c_0*c_6*y_0^3 + 4*c_0*y_0^4 - 4*c_1*c_6^4*y_0 + 6*c_1*c_6^4 - 16*c_1*c_6^3*y_0^2 + 24*c_1*c_6^3*y_0 - 24*c_1*c_6^2*y_0^3 + 36*c_1*c_6^2*y_0^2 - 16*c_1*c_6*y_0^4 + 24*c_1*c_6*y_0^3 - 4*c_1*y_0^5 + 6*c_1*y_0^4 - 4*c_2*c_6^3*y_0*y_2 + 6*c_2*c_6^3*y_2 - 12*c_2*c_6^2*y_0^2*y_2 + 12*c_2*c_6^2*y_0*y_2 + 4*c_2*c_6^2*y_2 - 12*c_2*c_6*y_0^3*y_2 + 6*c_2*c_6*y_0^2*y_2 + 4*c_2*c_6*y_0*y_2 + 4*c_2*c_6*y_2*yx16 + c_2*c_6*y_2 - 4*c_2*y_0^4*y_2)/(c_6^4 + 4*c_6^3*y_0 + 6*c_6^2*y_0^2 + 4*c_6*y_0^3 + y_0^4) - yx31*(4*c_1*c_6^5 + 20*c_1*c_6^4*y_0 + 40*c_1*c_6^3*y_0^2 + 40*c_1*c_6^2*y_0^3 + 20*c_1*c_6*y_0^4 + 4*c_1*y_0^5 + 4*c_2*c_6^4*y_2 + 12*c_2*c_6^3*y_0*y_2 + 6*c_2*c_6^3*y_2 + 12*c_2*c_6^2*y_0^2*y_2 + 12*c_2*c_6^2*y_0*y_2 + 4*c_2*c_6^2*y_2 + 4*c_2*c_6*y_0^3*y_2 + 6*c_2*c_6*y_0^2*y_2 + 4*c_2*c_6*y_0*y_2 + 4*c_2*c_6*y_2*yx16 + c_2*c_6*y_2)/(c_6^5 + 5*c_6^4*y_0 + 10*c_6^3*y_0^2 + 10*c_6^2*y_0^3 + 5*c_6*y_0^4 + y_0^5) + yx6*(6*c_0*c_6^3 + 18*c_0*c_6^2*y_0 + 18*c_0*c_6*y_0^2 + 6*c_0*y_0^3 + 6*c_1*c_6^3*y_0 - 4*c_1*c_6^3 + 18*c_1*c_6^2*y_0^2 - 12*c_1*c_6^2*y_0 + 18*c_1*c_6*y_0^3 - 12*c_1*c_6*y_0^2 + 6*c_1*y_0^4 - 4*c_1*y_0^3 + 6*c_2*c_6^2*y_0*y_2 - 4*c_2*c_6^2*y_2 + 12*c_2*c_6*y_0^2*y_2 - 4*c_2*c_6*y_0*y_2 - 4*c_2*c_6*y_2*yx16 - c_2*c_6*y_2 + 6*c_2*y_0^3*y_2)/(c_6^3 + 3*c_6^2*y_0 + 3*c_6*y_0^2 + y_0^3) + (-4*c_0*c_6*yx16 + c_0*c_6 - 4*c_0*y_0*yx16 + c_0*y_0 + 4*c_1*c_6*y_0*yx16 + c_1*c_6*y_0 + 4*c_1*y_0^2*yx16 + c_1*y_0^2 + 4*c_2*y_0*y_2*yx16 + c_2*y_0*y_2)/(c_6 + y_0)
```

and here is the temporary solution to the problem

```
temp <- 4*c_2*c_6*y_0^2*y_2*yx31 + 4*c_2*c_6*y_0^2*yx16*yx29 + c_2*c_6*y_0^2*yx29 - 4*c_2*c_6*y_0*y_2*yx16*yx31 - c_2*c_6*y_0*y_2*yx31 + 4*c_2*c_6*y_2*yx6^3*(20*y_0^2 + 24*yx6) + 6*c_2*c_6*y_2*yx6^3*(20*y_0^2 + 24*yx6)/y_0 + 4*c_2*c_6*y_2*yx6^3*(20*y_0^2 + 24*yx6)/y_0^2 + 4*c_2*c_6*y_2*yx16*yx6^3*(20*y_0^2 + 24*yx6)/y_0^3 + c_2*c_6*y_2*yx6^3*(20*y_0^2 + 24*yx6)/y_0^3 + 6*c_2*y_0^6*y_2*yx6 + c_2*y_0^6*y_2 + 6*c_2*y_0^6*yx14 - 4*c_2*y_0^6*yx29 - 4*c_2*y_0^6*yx4

dyx31 <- (6*c_0*c_6^6*yx6 + c_0*c_6^6 + 36*c_0*c_6^5*y_0*yx6 + 6*c_0*c_6^5*y_0 + 90*c_0*c_6^4*y_0^2*yx6 + 15*c_0*c_6^4*y_0^2 + 120*c_0*c_6^3*y_0^3*yx6 + 20*c_0*c_6^3*y_0^3 + 90*c_0*c_6^2*y_0^4*yx6 + 15*c_0*c_6^2*y_0^4 + 36*c_0*c_6*y_0^5*yx6 + 6*c_0*c_6*y_0^5 + 6*c_0*y_0^6*yx6 + c_0*y_0^6 + 6*c_1*c_6^6*y_0*yx6 + c_1*c_6^6*y_0 + 6*c_1*c_6^6*yx16 - 4*c_1*c_6^6*yx31 - 4*c_1*c_6^6*yx6 + 36*c_1*c_6^5*y_0^2*yx6 + 6*c_1*c_6^5*y_0^2 + 36*c_1*c_6^5*y_0*yx16 - 24*c_1*c_6^5*y_0*yx31 - 24*c_1*c_6^5*y_0*yx6 + 90*c_1*c_6^4*y_0^3*yx6 + 15*c_1*c_6^4*y_0^3 + 90*c_1*c_6^4*y_0^2*yx16 - 60*c_1*c_6^4*y_0^2*yx31 - 60*c_1*c_6^4*y_0^2*yx6 + 120*c_1*c_6^3*y_0^4*yx6 + 20*c_1*c_6^3*y_0^4 + 120*c_1*c_6^3*y_0^3*yx16 - 80*c_1*c_6^3*y_0^3*yx31 - 80*c_1*c_6^3*y_0^3*yx6 + 90*c_1*c_6^2*y_0^5*yx6 + 15*c_1*c_6^2*y_0^5 + 90*c_1*c_6^2*y_0^4*yx16 - 60*c_1*c_6^2*y_0^4*yx31 - 60*c_1*c_6^2*y_0^4*yx6 + 36*c_1*c_6*y_0^6*yx6 + 6*c_1*c_6*y_0^6 + 36*c_1*c_6*y_0^5*yx16 - 24*c_1*c_6*y_0^5*yx31 - 24*c_1*c_6*y_0^5*yx6 + 6*c_1*y_0^7*yx6 + c_1*y_0^7 + 6*c_1*y_0^6*yx16 - 4*c_1*y_0^6*yx31 - 4*c_1*y_0^6*yx6 + 6*c_2*c_6^5*y_0*y_2*yx6 + c_2*c_6^5*y_0*y_2 + 6*c_2*c_6^5*y_0*yx14 - 4*c_2*c_6^5*y_0*yx29 - 4*c_2*c_6^5*y_0*yx4 + 6*c_2*c_6^5*y_2*yx16 - 4*c_2*c_6^5*y_2*yx31 - 4*c_2*c_6^5*y_2*yx6 - 4*c_2*c_6^5*yx14 + 4*c_2*c_6^5*yx16*yx4 + 6*c_2*c_6^5*yx29 + c_2*c_6^5*yx4 + 30*c_2*c_6^4*y_0^2*y_2*yx6 + 5*c_2*c_6^4*y_0^2*y_2 + 30*c_2*c_6^4*y_0^2*yx14 - 20*c_2*c_6^4*y_0^2*yx29 - 20*c_2*c_6^4*y_0^2*yx4 + 24*c_2*c_6^4*y_0*y_2*yx16 - 16*c_2*c_6^4*y_0*y_2*yx31 - 16*c_2*c_6^4*y_0*y_2*yx6 - 16*c_2*c_6^4*y_0*yx14 + 16*c_2*c_6^4*y_0*yx16*yx4 + 24*c_2*c_6^4*y_0*yx29 + 4*c_2*c_6^4*y_0*yx4 - 4*c_2*c_6^4*y_2*yx16*yx6 + 4*c_2*c_6^4*y_2*yx16 - 6*c_2*c_6^4*y_2*yx31 - c_2*c_6^4*y_2*yx6 - 4*c_2*c_6^4*yx14*yx16 - c_2*c_6^4*yx14 + 4*c_2*c_6^4*yx29 + 4*c_2*c_6^4*y_2*yx6^3*(20*y_0^2 + 24*yx6)/y_0^3 + 60*c_2*c_6^3*y_0^3*y_2*yx6 + 10*c_2*c_6^3*y_0^3*y_2 + 60*c_2*c_6^3*y_0^3*yx14 - 40*c_2*c_6^3*y_0^3*yx29 - 40*c_2*c_6^3*y_0^3*yx4 + 36*c_2*c_6^3*y_0^2*y_2*yx16 - 24*c_2*c_6^3*y_0^2*y_2*yx31 - 24*c_2*c_6^3*y_0^2*y_2*yx6 - 24*c_2*c_6^3*y_0^2*yx14 + 24*c_2*c_6^3*y_0^2*yx16*yx4 + 36*c_2*c_6^3*y_0^2*yx29 + 6*c_2*c_6^3*y_0^2*yx4 - 12*c_2*c_6^3*y_0*y_2*yx16*yx6 + 12*c_2*c_6^3*y_0*y_2*yx16 - 18*c_2*c_6^3*y_0*y_2*yx31 - 3*c_2*c_6^3*y_0*y_2*yx6 - 12*c_2*c_6^3*y_0*yx14*yx16 - 3*c_2*c_6^3*y_0*yx14 + 12*c_2*c_6^3*y_0*yx29 + 4*c_2*c_6^3*y_2*yx16^2 + c_2*c_6^3*y_2*yx16 - 4*c_2*c_6^3*y_2*yx31 + 4*c_2*c_6^3*yx16*yx29 + c_2*c_6^3*yx29 + 12*c_2*c_6^3*y_2*yx6^3*(20*y_0^2 + 24*yx6)/y_0^2 + 6*c_2*c_6^3*y_2*yx6^3*(20*y_0^2 + 24*yx6)/y_0^3 + 60*c_2*c_6^2*y_0^4*y_2*yx6 + 10*c_2*c_6^2*y_0^4*y_2 + 60*c_2*c_6^2*y_0^4*yx14 - 40*c_2*c_6^2*y_0^4*yx29 - 40*c_2*c_6^2*y_0^4*yx4 + 24*c_2*c_6^2*y_0^3*y_2*yx16 - 16*c_2*c_6^2*y_0^3*y_2*yx31- 16*c_2*c_6^2*y_0^3*y_2*yx6 - 16*c_2*c_6^2*y_0^3*yx14 + 16*c_2*c_6^2*y_0^3*yx16*yx4 + 24*c_2*c_6^2*y_0^3*yx29 + 4*c_2*c_6^2*y_0^3*yx4 - 12*c_2*c_6^2*y_0^2*y_2*yx16*yx6 + 12*c_2*c_6^2*y_0^2*y_2*yx16 - 18*c_2*c_6^2*y_0^2*y_2*yx31 - 3*c_2*c_6^2*y_0^2*y_2*yx6 - 12*c_2*c_6^2*y_0^2*yx14*yx16 - 3*c_2*c_6^2*y_0^2*yx14 + 12*c_2*c_6^2*y_0^2*yx29 + 8*c_2*c_6^2*y_0*y_2*yx16^2 + 2*c_2*c_6^2*y_0*y_2*yx16 - 8*c_2*c_6^2*y_0*y_2*yx31 + 8*c_2*c_6^2*y_0*yx16*yx29 + 2*c_2*c_6^2*y_0*yx29 - 4*c_2*c_6^2*y_2*yx16*yx31 - c_2*c_6^2*y_2*yx31 + 12*c_2*c_6^2*y_2*yx6^3*(20*y_0^2 + 24*yx6)/y_0 + 12*c_2*c_6^2*y_2*yx6^3*(20*y_0^2 + 24*yx6)/y_0^2 + 4*c_2*c_6^2*y_2*yx6^3*(20*y_0^2 + 24*yx6)/y_0^3 + 30*c_2*c_6*y_0^5*y_2*yx6 + 5*c_2*c_6*y_0^5*y_2 + 30*c_2*c_6*y_0^5*yx14 - 20*c_2*c_6*y_0^5*yx29 - 20*c_2*c_6*y_0^5*yx4 + 6*c_2*c_6*y_0^4*y_2*yx16 - 4*c_2*c_6*y_0^4*y_2*yx31 - 4*c_2*c_6*y_0^4*y_2*yx6 - 4*c_2*c_6*y_0^4*yx14 + 4*c_2*c_6*y_0^4*yx16*yx4 + 6*c_2*c_6*y_0^4*yx29 + c_2*c_6*y_0^4*yx4 - 4*c_2*c_6*y_0^3*y_2*yx16*yx6 + 4*c_2*c_6*y_0^3*y_2*yx16 - 6*c_2*c_6*y_0^3*y_2*yx31 - c_2*c_6*y_0^3*y_2*yx6 - 4*c_2*c_6*y_0^3*yx14*yx16 - c_2*c_6*y_0^3*yx14 + 4*c_2*c_6*y_0^3*yx29 + 4*c_2*c_6*y_0^2*y_2*yx16^2 + c_2*c_6*y_0^2*y_2*yx16   - temp)/(c_6^6 + 6*c_6^5*y_0 + 15*c_6^4*y_0^2 + 20*c_6^3*y_0^3 + 15*c_6^2*y_0^4 + 6*c_6*y_0^5 + y_0^6)
```

They get longer and messier, so I would like to avoid having to do this repeatedly.

At the moment I've resorted to using a program called CVODE but I'd like to be able to do this in R if possible.

Comment: "Unexpected symbol" almost always means there's an operator such as `[` or a parenthesis `(` or `{` out of place or unbalanced. Check that out first.  Otherwise, please post the code in question for us to review.

Comment: There are *some* limitations to expression parsing, but they're very long.  It would help to have slightly more detail about what you're doing; are you storing equations in a character vector and then using `eval(parse(...))`?  Do you have very very long lines?  What is the length of the equation where you're running into trouble?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft If the equations weren't balanced why would storing half the equations in another vector solve the problem?

Comment: @BenBolker I've posted a sample equation causing an error and the temporary solution

Comment: Just a thought, but could you possibly simplify your underlying model? With that many variables (in the real world) noise is guaranteed to damage your estimates.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The simplification has been done as my needs be.